# Trace norm of a complex $|B| \times|A|$ matrix $M$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, mathematical-physics, trace

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, and let $M: A \rightarrow B$ be a $|B| \times|A|$ complex matrix. Show that the trace norm of $M$ can be expressed as
$$
\|M\|_{1}=\max _{V: B \rightarrow A} \operatorname{Tr}[V M]
$$
where the maximum is over all partial isometries $V: B \rightarrow A$.

$\mathbf{NOTE:}$ $V$ is a partial isometry if $V^*V=I^B$ or $VV^*=I^A$.

$\mathbf{ATTEMPT:}$ I have two ideas, one of them is that we have to show that $\max _{V: B \rightarrow A} \operatorname{Tr}[V M] \geqslant \|M\|_{1}$ and $\max _{V: B \rightarrow A} \operatorname{Tr}[V M] \leqslant \|M\|_{1}$. So then we can conclude $\|M\|_{1}=\max _{V: B \rightarrow A} \operatorname{Tr}[V M]$.

"$\leqslant$":The singular values of $M$ are $\mu_1 \geqslant \mu_2 \geqslant \cdots \geqslant \mu_n$ and the singular values of $V$ are $\nu_1 \geqslant \nu_2 \geqslant \cdots \geqslant \nu_n$.  Now, using von Neumann's trace inequality: $$\operatorname{Tr}[V M] \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i \nu_i \leqslant \max _{i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}} \{\nu_i\}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i \leqslant \nu_{max} \|M\|_{1} \leqslant \|M\|_{1}$$

But for the other direction I have no idea and I'm not sure that the above proof is true. I should mention that I'm also struggling to understand the von Neumann's trace inequality.

Could you please help me to complete the proof or give me an alternative proof?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answer is true, but not sure.

We can consider our partial isometry to be $V=\sum_{x=1}^{k} \left|u_x\right\rangle^A\left\langle v_x\right|^B $ where k is the minimum dimension between $|A|$ and $|B|$, $\{\left|u_x\right\rangle\}$  is an orthonormal set in $A$ and $\{\left|v_x\right\rangle\}$ is an orthonormal set in $B$. and we can write $M=\sum_{y=1}^{n} \left|s_y\right\rangle^B\left\langle r_y\right|^A$, where $\{\left|r_y\right\rangle\}$ and $\{\left|s_y\right\rangle\}$ are another orthonormal set in $A$ and $B$ respectively. So then $\operatorname{Tr}[VM]=\cdots=\sum_{x,y}^{} \mu_y \left\langle v_x \middle| s_y \right\rangle \left\langle r_y \middle| u_x \right\rangle$. So then, since $\left\langle v_x \middle| s_y \right\rangle , \left\langle r_y \middle| u_x \right\rangle \leqslant 1$ , then the maximum of the $\operatorname{Tr}[VM]$ occurs, if $\left\langle v_x \middle| s_y \right\rangle = \left\langle r_y \middle| u_x \right\rangle = \delta_{xy}$ and it depends on choosing the partial isometry. It means that $\max _{V: B \rightarrow A} \operatorname{Tr}[V M]=\max _{V: B \rightarrow A} \sum_{x,y}^{} \mu_y \left\langle v_x \middle| s_y \right\rangle \left\langle r_y \middle| u_x \right\rangle=\sum_{x,y}^{} \mu_y=\|M\|_1$.